# how to clean a Play project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.6

I want to clean my Play project. I haven't explicitly installed `Play`. It is a dependency in my `plugins.sbt` - `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.12")`.

How do I clean my project? If I run `play clean` on `cmd` (Windows 10), Windows cannot find `play`.

Comment: Have you tried to tun "clean"/"cleanFiles" from "sbt tasks" in SBT tool window?

Comment: i dont see these options in sbt tasks in Intellij 2018.5